# How to put a border under OL Li's

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out why the border extends out so much as well as doesn't put start at the number.

http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/

mockup:
http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/assets/images/wrestling2.jpg

```
    <div id="sidebar_left">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/ad.png" alt="Spotlight Wrestler"/></a>
        <div id="top5">
            <ol>
                <li>Joe Smith</li>
                <li>John Michaels</li>
                <li>Steve Hart</li>
                <li>Bret Hogan</li>
                <li>Undertaker</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>

#sidebar_left{width:300px;float:left;}
#sidebar_left img {}
#top5 ol li {padding:11px 0 11px 0;border-bottom:solid 1px gray;}
#top5 ol li:last-child{border:none;}
```

Comment: mockup link is dead. edit: nvm fixed

Comment: The border is 300px wide. You defined that width yourself (on the ancestor - the width of the LI's is equal to the width of the #sidebar_left DIV). What did you expect?

Comment: Real outlaws go for Quirks Mode! Seriously, consider including a doctype so that you're not at the whim of browser compatibility teams, and consider writing [valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fkansasoutlawwrestling.com%2F).

Comment: Okay I corrected all the mistakes but the rel error however how can I have it validate even with me using that attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will the LI's be links? Try making the text a link or just a span and then put the border on that element. Add padding to the left/right so it doesn't cling to the edges of the text. f you want the lines to be all the same width, give the parent ul a width.

See my mockup: http://jsfiddle.net/2kJJE/1/

Comment: The Lis are not links just text! I need it to extend as long as it appears on the left side of my mockup.

Comment: Even when I do that its still not adding the lines underneath the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The border is going to be the size of the width of the `li` which is going to be the width of the `ul`, which as a block level element is going to be the inner width of its container (width - padding).

The numbers/bullets will be rendered depending on the `list-style-position`. If that property is set to `outside` then they will render outside the `li`. Usually that outside space is accounted for in the padding of the `ol`/'ul`. If set to inside then they will render inside the`li` however text will wrap as normal so your content for each item wont be indented from the number/bullet.